# Magento 1.9 not showing pagination

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, pagination

I'm using Magento's default theme (rwd) as a base for my first work with magento, my client inserted some products but the pagination is not showing!

The products page was done by a CMS page in the admin with the code:
`{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/produtos.phtml"}}`
in it.

It is calling the toolbar and a "`<p class="amount amount--has-pages"> 1-12 de 68</p>`" in it
But no paging :(

here's the link, it's in Portuguese

http://zoio-magento.jelastic.websolute.net.br/index.php/produtos/

Comment: Why don't you use the default category pages? They will have Pagination built in.

Comment: Sorry, but, How do I use them?

Comment: You can setup a category and add all your products and by default you will see paging

Comment: They already are all in a default category, but how do I get the category page? I mean whats the link for category id=4, for example

Comment: Can someone help me plz? My pagiantion apears in my related_products page but it don't apears in my products/list :(

Comment: Switch to the default theme, your pagination should work - if it doesn't work then you have a problem with your Magento install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this page with my answer: http://www.noamdesign.com/magento-include-toolbar-and-pagination-when-listing-products/

Just needed to edit the Layout Update XML field in the design tab at my CMS product page
After that had a trouble with "double" phtml, fixed it excluding the `{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/produtos.phtml"}}` in my content page :)